# SoftKeyboard hides edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, window-soft-input-mode

I have an `EdiText` at the bottom of my layout.The issue I was having is that when it gets focus the screen shifts upwards to give space to soft keyboard.To resolve it I added

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

inside my `Activity` declaration in **manifest**.Now the problem is that the edittext hides behind the softkeyboard although screen doesn't shifts.
If instead I put

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

then the activity's main window shifts upward which i don't want.
How can i resolve this in such way that when `EdiText` gets focus  activity's main window does NOT shift upwards to make room for the soft keyboard but the main window is resized including the `EdiText` so that keyboard comes below `EdiText` as seen in many apps.

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background_feed">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />



    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/comments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F7F7F7"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/border_view_comment"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/no_comment_msg"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/border_view_comment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/commentlayout"
        android:background="#C7C7C7"
        android:visibility="gone"/>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/commentlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/comment_box_shadow"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/commentor_image"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/clickPostComment"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/post"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/commentsPost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/commentor_image"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/clickPostComment"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/commentor_image"
            android:background="@drawable/comment_edittext_bg"
            android:hint="Comments"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:maxLength="140"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/title_gray"
            android:textColorHint="#d5d5d5"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/commentsPost"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="-2dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/commentsPost"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/comment_shape" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

make your view scrollable  by embed your view inside `Scrollview`

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   .....
    add your layout
   ......

</ScrollView>
```

If that doesn't help make you root layout as `RelativeLayout` and design your layout with  `RelativeLayout`

Comment: if i use ScrollView then my whole layout design changes..Originally my layout consist of list and below the list there is a comment box(edittext)..if i put entire layout inside scroll view then my edittext moves to top of the screen and i can't see list..i am already using relative layout..i have posted in question originally hows my layout

Comment: and that is why you use the scrollView you can't see all your view when keyboard appear so all you can do is hide one of the views by scrolling and it's the logical way to do that

Comment: if i use scrollview i can see only the edittext layout (`commentlayout` as in xml in question) no matter whether the softkeyboard is hidden or shown and that also on top of screen..why is tht happening?

Comment: try to add this to your scrollView android:fillViewport="true"

Comment: Please post your xml with scrollview